# Combine the varying number of rows to one row in Data Factory in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, derived-column

I am so new in Azure Data Factory, and I have a problem solving this problem. I wanted to combine varying number of rows in to one row base on the substring of the first column , I know that I can use collect() but the problem is I don't have a key column.

Here is my data in csv file looks like

PREC001  NY
DREC12023 ALKBY23
PREC001  NJ
DREC23545
AREC20210728 2.30
...

And I wanted the output to be like
PREC001  NY DREC12023 ALKBY23
PREC001  NJ DREC23545 AREC20210728 2.30
....

So I wanted to combine multiple rows to one and start the new row if the row starts with 'PREC', you can see that the number of rows that will be combined is varying.

Comment: Is there any specific pattern of "PREC' and other rows occurrence? are they repeating after any particular number? you can create key column in your dataset using Surrogate Key transformation in mapping data. follow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-surrogate-key

Comment: Have you considered replacing "PREC" with "|PREC" then handling it using "|" as the row delimiter? You can just do the replace via a Data Flow then copy activity with "|" as teh row delimiter and that should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to @Trent Tamara logic , i introduced a derived column and used the below expression to replace

> iif(like(Column_1,'%PREC%'),replace(Column_1, 'PREC',
> '|PREC'),Column_1)

Just to add I have to writew to a blob file with the replaced values and then read the file with a row delimiter as "|" . I am not sure why it never woked with the write operation .